# Python QT on Azure

Tags: qt, azure, pyside

I'm using Python and QT (PySide) in a local application (which connect to a database on cloud Azure).

Now, my objective is moving this app on the web, in particular on Azure (I have an Azure subscription), simply transfering it on Azure, it's possible in some manner? I have not found examples on the web.

The important question is: is Python QT (app web) compatible with Azure?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *app web*?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER!**

Yes, now you can. Well sort of. The mad mads at Digia have created something called "QT for Web Assembly" that can compile your whole app into something that runs embedded into a web page.
https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-setup-webassembly.html
You might have to rethink connecting directly to the database however, as thats simply not gonna fly with web-sockets (And honestly direct app to remote RDBMS has never been a smart move. Theres a LOT of things that can go wrong letting the internet connnect to your databaes). But you could at least keep the UI and rewrite the databaes layer to interogate something like a GraphQL (or whatever) front end to the data.

**OLD ANSWER**

I'm afraid your up for a nearly complete rewrite. QT is a desktop/mobile platform. It doesn't go anywhere near HTML/CSS except perhaps for displaying them in a webview component. Azure or AWS won't magically make it into a web application for you.

Your code as it stands needd to be rewritten in a web-first transactional manner. That is it takes a request, processes it, produces a result. To some extent websockets has changed this dynamic for a limited subset of use cases where interaction needs to be non transactional, and modern web app design hides much of the transactionality behind a web-services model, but 90% of web work is still very much transactional.

Database <---> Web server/Web app stack <--- Internet! --> Web browser

My suggestion is to pick up Django (or one of the other systems. If its just simple, Flask is another good alternative. Flask for simple apps, Django for the big stuff. Or use something else, you have choices here!, and start from scratch. Analyse your products function and start mapping out how to make this work as a database driven transactional system.

Theres no shortcuts here, I'm afraid.

Comment: I should note: I absolutely do not recomend writing web apps this way, QT over wasm or whatever... Hell, I'm hardly a fan of the react/vue/etc way of doing things. Your clients want web pages, not desktop apps awkwardly jammed into a web-browser